# Can non-anonymous functions in PHP using 'use' keyword?

Tags: php, closures

Can non-anonymous functions in PHP using 'use' keyword? Or it is available for anonymous functions only.

Can I write a php file like this

```
// L.php
// assume $_texts is in this context..

$_language = null;

function L_init($language) use (&$_language)
{
  $_language = $language;
}

function L($key) use ($_texts, $_language)
{
  $_texts[$_language][$key];
}
```

So, another file can use it like this

```
// client.php
require_once 'L.php';

L_init('en');
echo L('GREETING'); // Will output localize string of key 'GREETING'
```

Comment: You could simply try it. :) You'll find the answer is: no.

Comment: `Answer = (Does the code compile without syntax errors?)`

Comment: Thanks both of you. The code doesn't compile, so the answer is: no

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No you can't.

The code generate syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

It is available for anonymous functions, but you can assign it to a variable:

```
$some_external_var = "World!";
$function = function() use($some_external_var){
    echo "Hello ".$some_external_var;
};
```

Finally you can invoke it with:

```
call_user_func($function);
```

or just:

```
$function();
```