# What is the scope of CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION?

Tags: php, rest, curl

TIA for your help.

I'm am making a call to an external REST API using cURL. The call works fine.
As part of the cURL options I'm using CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION to parse the response headers, like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "parseResponseHeaders");
```

And the functions looks like this:

```
function parseResponseHeaders($ch, $header_line ) {
    if(preg_match("/Location/i", $header_line)){
        $break_header = explode(": ", $header_line);
        $build_new_string = $break_header[1].$string_from_outside_this_function;
    }
    return strlen($header_line);
}
```

The problem I have is that the "$string_from_outside_this_function" variable returns as undefined.

I understand that the "parseResponseHeaders" callback accepts 2 parameters. So I cannot pass the outside variable.
I'm assuming that the outside variable is not in scope. However, the code above is contained in a parent function (method). 
And the outside variable is available anywhere else inside the parent function.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is an anonymous function, you can use the `use` keyword to inject a variable in the same scope as where the function is defined into the body of the function.

It would look something like this:

```
$string_from_outside_this_function = 'Testing';

$parseResponseHeaders = function ($ch, $header_line) use ($string_from_outside_this_function) {
    //Thanks to the "use" keyword, "Testing" has been injected as the value of
    //$string_outside_this_function variable
    if (preg_match("/Location/i", $header_line)) {
        $break_header = explode(": ", $header_line);
        $build_new_string = $break_header[1].$string_from_outside_this_function;
    }

    return strlen($header_line);
}
```

Now that your anonymous function is defined, you can pass it in your `curl_setopt` call like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, $parseResponseHeaders);
```

This assumes that where your `curl_setopt` call occurs has the anonymous function's variable within scope. In other words, you can't create the anonymous function in one scope, and call `curl_setopt` in a different scope, and expect to have `$parseResponseHeaders` be defined. That would essentially bring you back to your original scoping problem in a different place.

Here's PHP's documentation on anonymous functions, which includes the `use` keyword: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

It's important to note that a named function **cannot** use the `use` keyword, only anonymous functions. That's answered here, for reference: [Can non-anonymous functions in PHP using 'use' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667918/can-non-anonymous-functions-in-php-using-use-keyword)

Comment: Thank you very much @stratedge. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: Not a problem @jnkrois, happy to help!